# rails4: image_tag generates a 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In production the generated html for the image_tag helper returns a 404 error.
Asset pipeline is enabled

In the haml file

```
=image_tag "how_it_works_1.jpg"
```

how_it_works_1.jpg file is located at app/assets/images/how_it_works_1.jpg

When I deploy in production with mina I can find this asset under current/public/assets/how_it_works_1-5e40b2326fc14e879ae476a3fd6aef97.jpg

however the generated html doesn't point to this asset but to /images/how_it_works_1.jpg which returns a 404

```
<img src="/images/how_it_works_1.jpg"/>
```

it's working under the development env

```
<img src="/assets/how_it_works_1.jpg"/>
```

edit:
I am using apache2.4 together with passenger
here is an extract of my production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run this first. I've had this issue myself before.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

and then reload the server.

Comment: that was the solution. I was skeptical because the deploy.rb script already has a precompiling rule

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your assets are precompiling successfully. However, Rails defaults to refusing to serve static assets in production. [This Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) has a bit more information. (Ctrl-F for `config.serve_static_assets`)

To answer your question, you will need to configure your web server (is it Apache, nginx, or something else?) to serve the static assets from your deploy's `public/assets/` directory.

If you edit your question to include your web server, I can give you a link to more specific instructions. Cheers!

Comment: I am using apache2.4 + passenger. I edited the question

Comment: Okay, I think you will want a line like `Alias /assets /path/to/currents/public/assets/` in your Apache's configuration file. Though in retrospect I am not positive that this will help, because [it seems like Passenger should already serve static assets](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_static_assets_serving). Perhaps you can provide some more clues, like the Unix file permissions of the public/assets/ directory?

Comment: Have you tried my answer of precompiling the assets? I don't think the problem is with the server, it's with the link that's being generated.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Glad that worked, but I'm a bit perplexed because the asset was already precompiled - as evidenced by the digested filename being present in the public/assets folder. Maybe there was no `manifest.json` file in the directory before? Weird...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `config.assets.digest` is not true in config/environments/production.rb (by default it should be true).

Comment: it's set to true - I edited my question to add the relevant section of  production.rb in